# Simple webshop-plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

Im looking for a simple plugin to make a site from which i can make orders for products.
The whole shop should be under an own "tab" in the menu. It should be possible to use nested categories. Each product have an "Add to cart" button, and a textfield to enter the quantity. When the user is finished, they fill out their name and address and such, and an email is sent to the store keeper with all of the information about added items and information about the buyer.

Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [WooCommerce](http://woothemes.com/woocommerce/). Everything you're asking for it will handle.

Comment: "_Everything you're asking for it will handle._" - No it doesn't. And this line is just too generous. Are you affiliated with Woo?

Comment: I am not in any way. What won't it handle?

Comment: Lots of stuff. For ex. not compatible with german eCommerce right.